# How to change Geometry Nodes modifier name to node tree name?

Tags: python, modifiers, node-editor, interface, geometry-nodes

Is it possible in Blender 3.3 to name each Geometry Nodes modifier name to be the same as the name of node tree attached to this modifier?

Of course, it can be done manually, but for projects with a lot of objects, node trees and Geometry Nodes modifiers, it would be much better to do it via python, change settings or other more automated solution.

This is especially useful for objects with a lot of modifiers. Thanks to this solution, having the modifier window collapsed, you can see what node tree was attached to the Geometry Nodes modifier.

Thanks alot in advance, if something is unclear, i can provide more info or pictures.

[image]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no automatic solution to do this. The only way to get this done would be a python-based enhancement.

Comment: Thank for comment. It is a pity that there is no such option in the settings :c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this python script:

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    for mod in o.modifiers:
        if mod.type == "NODES":
            mod.name = mod.node_group.name
```

Comment: This script works great, thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome